# Bat file set classpath

Tags: java, class, batch-file, classpath

Can you see anything wrong with the below code? It's a bat file and I'm trying to set some dependency classes before executing my jar (jdbc oracle driver).

```
set CLASSPATH=lib\dbdriver.zip;%CLASSPATH%
java -jar sql2java.jar test.properties
pause
```

I always get class not found exception (the class is in the zip I'm trying to add in the classpath).
I even tried this by executing as admin, but to no avail

```
set CLASSPATH=lib\dbdriver.zip;%CLASSPATH%
java -jar %~dp0sql2java.jar %~dp0test.properties
pause
```

The class is inside the zip file (path \oracle\jdbc\OracleDriver) and I'm trying to retrieve it with

> jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) about `java` (Java application launcher).

For the `-jar` option it says -

> Executes a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. For this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line in the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class with the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your application's starting point.
>
> **When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

So you either need to package everything in your jar (`sql2java.jar`) or don't use the `-jar` option with `java` launcher command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java -jar to execute it and define a classpath for the application within the jar's manifest file. See the Java Tutorial on jars for how to set a classpath for the application at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

It says:

> For example, in a typical situation an applet is bundled in a JAR file
>   whose manifest references a different JAR file (or several different
>   JAR files) that serves as utilities for the purposes of that applet.
>
> You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the
>   manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes
>   the following form:
>
> ```
> Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
> ```
>
> By using the Class-Path header in the manifest, you can avoid having
>   to specify a long -classpath flag when invoking Java to run the your
>   application.